# Integrate $\exp(-2\lambda)(2r\lambda'-1)/r^2 + (1/r^2)$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

How to integrate the expression? $\lambda=\lambda(r)$
$$\exp(-2\lambda)\left( \frac{2\lambda^{\prime}}{r}-\frac{1}{r^2}\right)+\frac{1}{r^2}=0$$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: CAS says:$\left\{\left\{L(x)\to -\ln \left(-\sqrt{\frac{e^{2
   c_1}}{x}+1}\right)\right\},\left\{L(x)\to
   -\frac{1}{2} \ln \left(\frac{e^{2
   c_1}}{x}+1\right)\right\}\right\}$

Comment: Looking for $\exp(-2\lambda)=f(r)$

Comment: What is $L(x)$ here?

Comment: @LostinSpace.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\exp(-2\lambda)\left( \frac{2\lambda^{\prime}}{r}-\frac{1}{r^2}\right)+\frac{1}{r^2}=0$$
Substitute:
$$u=e^{-2\lambda} \implies u'=-2e^{-2\lambda}\lambda '$$
$$ \implies 2\lambda '= -\dfrac {u'}{u}$$
The differential equation becomes:
$$u\left( \dfrac{ - {u'}}{ur}-\frac{1}{r^2}\right)+\frac{1}{r^2}=0$$
More simply:
$$ r {u'}+{u}=1$$
$$(ru)'=1$$
Integrate.
$$\boxed {e^{-2\lambda}=\dfrac C r+1}$$

Comment: Elegant solution!

Comment: @Tursinbay Thank you ....